# wget recursion and file extraction

Tags: linux, screen-scraping, wget

I'm trying to use wget to elegantly & politely download all the pdfs from a website.  The pdfs live in various sub-directories under the starting URL.  It appears that the -A pdf option is conflicting with the -r option.  But I'm not a wget expert!  This command:

`wget -nd -np -r site/path`

faithfully traverses the entire site downloading everything downstream of path (not polite!).  This command:

`wget -nd -np -r -A pdf site/path`

finishes immediately having downloaded nothing.  Running that same command in debug mode:

`wget -nd -np -r -A pdf -d site/path`

reveals that the sub-directories are ignored with the debug message:

> Deciding whether to enqueue "https://site/path/subdir1". https://site/path/subdir1 (subdir1) does not match acc/rej rules. Decided NOT to load it.

I think this means that the sub directories did not satisfy the "pdf" filter and were excluded.  Is there a way to get wget to recurse into sub directories (of random depth) and only download pdfs (into a single local dir)?  Or does wget need to download everything and then I need to manually filter for pdfs afterward?

UPDATE:  thanks to everyone for their ideas.  The solution was to use a two step approach including a modified version of this:  http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/generate-list-of-urls-using-wget/

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: thanks to everyone for their ideas. The solution was to use a two step approach including a modified version of this: http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/generate-list-of-urls-using-wget/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1)the “-l” switch specifies to wget to go one level down from the primary URL specified. You could obviously switch that to how ever many levels down in the links you want to follow.

```
wget -r -l1 -A.pdf http://www.example.com/page-with-pdfs.htm
```

refer `man wget` for more details

2. if the above doesn't work,try this

   verify that the TOS of the web site permit to crawl it. Then, one solution is :

   mech-dump --links 'http://example.com' |
   grep pdf$ |
   sed 's/\s+/%20/g' |
   xargs -I% wget http://example.com/%
   The mech-dump command comes with Perl's module WWW::Mechanize (libwww-mechanize-perl package on debian & debian likes distros

for installing mech-dump

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libwww-mechanize-shell-perl
```

github repo https://github.com/libwww-perl/WWW-Mechanize

3. I haven't tested this, but you cans still give a try, what i think is you still need to find a way to get all URLs of a website and pipe to any of the solutions I have given.

You will need to have wget and lynx installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wget lynx
```

Prepare a script name it however you want for this example pdflinkextractor

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    WEBSITE="$1"
    
    echo "Getting link list..."
    
    lynx -cache=0 -dump -listonly "$WEBSITE" | grep ".*\.pdf$" | awk '{print $2}' | tee pdflinks.txt
    
       
    
    echo "Downloading..."    
    wget -P pdflinkextractor_files/ -i pdflinks.txt
```

to run the file

```
chmod 700 pdfextractor
$  ./pdflinkextractor http://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Free-Sample-PDF-Files-with-scripts.cfm
```

Comment: Using -r -l1 still results in the "...does not match acc/rej rules." message with nothing downloaded.  Since the sub directories are of varying depths, I've also tried -m.  But the root cause seems to be that the sub directories do not match the pdf filter.  So I think this may need to be a 2-step solution.

Comment: Clever approach, unfortunately, mech-dump only seems to grab the top level links and doesn't descend into sub directories.  Since there are no pdfs at the top level, nothing is returned.  Thanks for the novel approach, though!

Comment: if it helped you in any way, you can upvote it so that it may help others in future.

Comment: lynx was a good idea, but it seems to not recurse (same with mech-dump).  I have upvoted your answer but I have no reputation.  Sorry about that - and thanks for your help!

Comment: I am working on a better solution for your problem, give me some time.